# Could I put sensitive information in an iOS app's source code?

Tags: ios, swift, security, passwords

I'm building an app for students at my high school. Every week the app needs to check if school will be in session that week. The only place this is shown is on ASPEN, which shows students their grades and schedules.

The issue is, I can't just web scrape it, as the user has to be logged in to see anything. I don't have a server, so if I were to do this I would need to store my password on other peoples phones. I can't make them enter their own passwords, as the school would shut my ass down instantly.

I'm not worried about master hackers, only high schoolers who have access to youtube. I don't think anyone would even try, but the school is semi-involved with this project, and I need to be able to say that I'm not just throwing my password to the wind.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm new to iOS development.

Comment: Could you not store teh passwords on firebase. Also if you mean live in the code: No its not a problem

Comment: If your main concern is about security, rest assured it's actually very difficult if not impossible to reverse engineer / decompile an iOS app.

Comment: If school is involved why not create test user instead of putting your credentials. you can also limit access to the test user.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use an [obscurator](https://gist.github.com/DejanEnspyra/80e259e3c9adf5e46632631b49cd1007).

It protects you sensitive data in case your app is reverse engineered.